# My initial useEffect hook is running two times and appends to my array the same element twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

So I am creating an app using the REST countries API and I have a useEffect hook that runs on the empty dependency array and I am expecting it to run once and I am trying to append to my array all the types of currencies associated with the country but for some reason the useEffect runs twice and appends the same currency twice to my array and I would like to know why that is. Any help is much appreciated.

my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
       axios.get(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${countryName}`).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data[0])
        setData({
            name: countryName,
            image: response.data[0].flags.png,
            nativeName: response.data[0].name.nativeName.nld,
            population: response.data[0].population,
            region: response.data[0].region,
            subRegion: response.data[0].subregion,
            capital: response.data[0].capital[0],
            borderCountries: response.data[0].borders,
            topLevelDomain: response.data[0].tld[0],
            currencies: response.data[0].currencies,
            languages: response.data[0].languages,
        })
        
        for (let k in response.data[0].currencies) {
            setCurrencies(prev => [...prev, k])
        }
       }) 
    },[])
```

[image: The output]

Comment: Did you use any other `useEffect` in your code?

Comment: this is due to the strict mode in index.js file

Comment: D. Nguyen, this is the only useEffect used in the component.

Comment: Amir Shahzad, I see removing it solved the problem. Would removing it affect my project at all in the future?